# Example code of FBML App that uses signed_request?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, fbml, oauth-2.0

We did not know that Oct 1 is also deadline for signed_request.
Does anyone have example code to do signed_request for FBML apps?
We are trying to beat the deadline on Oct 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [signed_request documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) shows how to do it in PHP.  It's pretty easy to do in any language.

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```